# The solution to $x^n = -1$ over finite field.

Tags: galois-theory

From [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58357/number-of-n-th-roots-of-unity-over-finite-fields), I understand how to find the number of $n$th roots of unity.

I would like to know how to find the number of solutions to this equation:
$$
x^n = -1
$$
over the finite field $F_q$ with $q$ elements ($n$ is fixed).

My only thoughts on this is that it looks like finding $n$th roots of unity like in the other question. I can see that if $n$ is odd, then $-1$ is a solution. I can see that if $n$ is equal to $q-1$, then there are no solutions since the order of the group $F_q^X$ is $q-1$.

Comment: It seems there is a perfectly accurate answer in the link you provided?

Comment: @Marc: But I don't want the roots of unity ... ?

Comment: Ah... My bet...

Answer (score 4):

The solutions to $x^n=-1$ are precisely the primitive $(2n)$th roots of unity.

For any $m$ and any field $F$, if $F$ contains a primitive $m$th root of unity then the exact number of them it contains is $\varphi(m)$. The field $\Bbb F_q$ contains a primitive $m$th root of unity iff $m\mid(q-1)$.